# Scan HTable rows for column value between two timestamp

Tags: database, nosql, hbase, hbase-shell

Scan HTable rows for column value between two timestamp. Timestamp filter & setTimeRange works on the timestamp set by hbase, but in my case I have a difference column which contains the timestamp and want to make a query on that timestamp. So is there any filter or way to filter out the records which are lying only in the given time range.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ValueFilter . If the column contains unix timestamp, you need to pass **greater than** and **less than** condition in the **FILTER** comparator.

```
scan '<your-table>', { COLUMNS => 'cf:column', LIMIT => 3, FILTER => "ValueFilter( >,
'binaryprefix:mintimeStamp') AND ValueFilter( =, 'binaryprefix:max-timestamp')" }
```